# VS2010 Publish website not copying some files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

My web application has two build configurations, Dev and Prod. There is a custom build step that will copy some extra config files to the bin folder, and the files are different depending on the build configuration.

This all works well when I do a build, but when I Publish to a FileSystem, these files are not copied over from my bin folder to the publish destination path. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: How are you copying your files?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the "Copy Local" property to true?
When you publish to the local file system, this will copy the files locally.

[image: Copy local]